# Generation of sequences of styles with some pattern

Tags: css, less

I need to generate some utility classes in **Less** like `margin-top-10`, `margin-bottom-20`, etc. Currently I'm doing it now very effectively I believe like this:

```
.margin {
    &-bottom {
        &-5 {
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        &-10 {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        &-20 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        &-30 {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
    }

    &-top {
        &-5 {
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
        &-10 {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        &-20 {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        &-30 {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way in **Less** to create something like procedure that will generate it like

```
margin-utility([<direction>, <direction>, <direction>], [<value>, <value>, value>]);
```

**E.g.**

```
margin-utility(['top', 'bottom'], [5, 10, 15, 20, 30]);
```

Comment: Yes have a look at loops.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I doubt it'd be very hard to program this in some scripting language, say javascript.

Comment: I cringe whenever I see this. Just use `style="margin-top:10px"` if you want a top-margin of 10px. It won't kill you! Alternatively, separate HTML and CSS *properly*.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note:** It sounds like really bad practice to create individual classes for each margin direction and size combination. They would become very tedious maintain and so I wouldn't recommend it. But the answer to your question is - *Yes, you can do it with Less.*

You can use Less loops to iterate through the list of values, directions and then create the selectors and property-value pairs using interpolation. Below is a sample code (inline comments added for the purpose of clarity/explanation).

```
@values: 5, 10, 15, 20, 30; /* the values */

.margin-utility(@values; @directions...){ /* utility wrapper mixin which takes values and directions */
    .loop-directions(@i) when (@i > 0) { /* iterate through each direction value */
        @direction: extract(@directions, @i);
        .create-margin(@values; @direction); /* call margin creation mixin with current direction */
        .loop-directions(@i - 1); /* call next iteration */
    }
    .loop-directions(length(@directions)); /* call first iteration */
}
.create-margin(@values; @direction){ /* mixin to loop through values and create classes */
    .loop-values(@j) when (@j > 0) { /* iterate through each value */
        @value: extract(@values, @j);
        .margin-@{direction}-@{value}{ /* create selector through selector interpolation */
            margin-@{direction}: unit(@value, px); /* create property through property interpolation */
        }
        .loop-values(@j - 1);
    }
    .loop-values(length(@values));
}
.margin-utility(@values; top, bottom, left);
```

Comment: I was thinking about how bad practice is to creating margin set, so what is your option for this?

Comment: @AliTorabi: Creating one class for each margin size and direction is definitely bad because it bloats up your code. It is much better to write the properties within the respective element/class selectors. If multiple elements share the same properties then the selectors can be grouped.